# What kind of parameter should a web-service function that accepts a json string from a jquery ajax call have?

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, json

I want to store the positions of some elements on the front-end(jQuery) in the Database. I'm adding these to an array, using json to stringify the array and then attempting to store this to the DB through a web service in .NET. However, if I remove the parameter from the web-service and just call it to check if it works, I can see that it does. However, as soon as I pass a parameter, I get a missing parameter error. I think this has to do with my web-service functions parameter data type being incorrect.

### This is what the function looks like in the .asmx file

```
[WebMethod]
    public void submitToDB(**Object jsonObj**) - not sure what the datatype here should be
    {
        string jsonOb = "meghu";
        string commandText = "INSERT into HackDemo(JSONobj) VALUES (@jsonObject)";
        string connectionString = "Data Source=sqldeva05;Initial Catalog=IRNdev;Integrated Security=True;";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);                
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jsonObject", jsonOb);

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                Int32 rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

### Heres what the ajax call from jquery looks like -

```
           $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',                       
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: 'dbFunctions.asmx/submitToDB',
                    data: JSON.stringify(myArray),
                    success: function () { alert("success"); },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I'm not really sure why you've tagged this with the jquery and ajax tags when the actual question is about the server-side implementation (which has nothing to do with jQuery or AJAX). Even if you keep those tags, one that corresponds to your server-side technology would be beneficial, since knowledge about that is crucial to answering the question.

Comment: Actually, the issue here was with the way I was calling the web-service via my client side ajax call in jquery. I think the tags may have been helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a class in the server side code and make it serializable.  Then just match the public variables/properties up in the javascript and pass it to the webmethod on the server.

On the web server

```
[Serializable]
public class Foo
{
    public string PersonName;
    public string [] StringArray;
}

[WebMethod]
public void DoWork(Foo myParameter) 
{
// Server logic here
}
```

In your Javascript file

```
var obj = {
PersonName = personName,
StringArray = stringArray
}

var DTO = { "myParameter" = obj }  // You want the parameter name in DTO to match the name of the parameter in the webmethod

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',                       
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'dbFunctions.asmx/DoWork',
    data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
    success: function () { alert("success"); },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @NuNn DaDdY, this worked like a charm. Although I believe my JSON String was well formed. I racked my brains for quite a few hours trying to get this right!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var myData = {
    param1: 'thisisparam1',
    param2: 'thisisparam2'
};

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',                       
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'dbFunctions.asmx/submitToDB',
        data: myData,
        success: function () { alert("success"); },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Also, the 'data' param can be a string... like this:

```
data: 'param1=one&param2=two&param3=three'
```

Maybe you are confused by this: dataType: 'json' ... this is the type of data that you're expecting back from the server

Greatings.